# How do I flip/rotate a resistor in CircuiTikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, rotating

How can I flip a resistor in CircuiTikZ?. Some thing like a , or

```
rotate = 180
```

or

```
yscale = -1
```

but for a resistor.

In other words my resistors looks like this:

[image]

and I am trying to make it look like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

I have tried using the rotate, yscale commands, but to no avail. I have also tried doing this part of the circuit from left to right and from right to left but that didn't do it either...

Comment: [mirror image] or [invert] (see page 166).  Invert is more use for things with polarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mirror` (vertical axis) or `invert` (horizontal, that in this case does the same, because the shape is symmetric).

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,1) to[R] ++(2,0);
    \draw (0,0) to[R=mirror, mirror] ++(2,0);
    \draw (0,-1) to[R=invert, invert] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`yscale` and `xscale`, as well as `rotate`, are not supposed to work inside a `to[]` command. They will work on the node shape:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node [resistorshape](r1) at (0,1) {};
    \node [resistorshape, yscale=-1](r0) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You so so much!!!. Been searching online for hours and couldn't find anything. Also figured out why I wasn't able to draw a resistor node standalone (was trying to do \node [resistor]), but it's actually \node [resistorshape]. Thanks a lot once again!

Comment: You're welcome. There is a section in the manual called "flipping and mirroring" ;-)